# C# draw problems

Tags: c#, draw

I have a problem when I try to draw a rectangle or something on the screen. In this code I will expect to draw a rectangle on the coordinate x = 0 and y = half of the screen, but it isn't in the center of the screen.

Thank you !

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Graphics gr;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            gr = this.CreateGraphics();

            Pen p = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black),1);

            gr.DrawRectangle(p, 0, this.Height / 2 - 50, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

> this.Height

returns form height with titlebar height. To draw a rectangle with next coordinates: x = 0, y = half of the screen, you can use next code:

```
    protected void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       gr = this.CreateGraphics();
       Pen p = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 1);
       gr.DrawRectangle(p, 0, ClientRectangle.Height / 2 - 50, 100, 100);
    }
```

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to mark answer as correct answer to close the question.